# Unity Particle System Setup like Club Penguin Dance Contest

Tags: unity-game-engine, particle-system

I am building an arrow game. I want to create something that reminisces this "poof", but in black.
How would I achieve that using a Particle System? What settings do I need? I don't want something that's exactly the same, I'm interested in the "poof" animation.

Example:
[Club Penguin Dance Contest Video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ssz67DKR3mc)

Comment: Im not sure its done with the particle system, but as you can provide the mesh if you could make a cloud shape mesh you probably could

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You dont need Particle System to create this effect at all.

I think the best way is to do it using **Animation Spritesheet**.

You can take similar spritesheet from this guide about [Using UIImageView for animate a sequence of images](http://blog.victorbaro.com/2013/04/uiimageview-animation/), and combine it with this guide about [Using Spritesheets with Unity3D](http://www.strandedsoft.com/using-spritesheets-with-unity3d/).

This will give you this result:

[image]

Comment: The particle system was causing trouble anyway since I had to use screen space - camera, and my game wasn't designed with this in mind.

Comment: Sorry, @Vlad.K. I just got a question ban due to many of my questions being negatively voted. If you think my question really deserves -1 points, leave it like that. If you think it was an actual decent question, could you please upvote it so I have 0 points on it, so my question ban will be lifted? Thanks!